# Firestore rules are not filter - one more clarification

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need a clarification on the infamous ["Rules are not filter"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters)

Imagine

- a collection `testcol` with documents that all have a field `test` with value `1`.
- a rule for this collection `allow list: if resource.data.test == 1`
- a query that pulls all the documents from this collection: `firebase.collection(testcol).get()`

So even if the query does not explicitly specify a filter on the field `test`, all returned documents still pass the rule.

I am testing this now and I see that I am still getting a "Missing or insufficient permissions" error! So is the rule engine not only checking the documents accessed against the rules but also checking the query itself to see if it might theoretically return documents not matching the rules, regardless of the documents themselves?

Answer (score 2):

Firestore doesn't actively check each existing document to see if it matches the conditions. That would never scale.

It instead checks if the read operation is guaranteed to **ever** only return allowed documents, no matter the actual underlying data. If it can't guarantee that, the read is rejected as it is here.

Comment: Now there is something I don't understand: how can it "check if the read operation is guaranteed to ever only return allowed documents"??? In some case this may not be possible in the general case without actually checking each returned document

Comment: Can you give an example of such a case?

Comment: 'allow list: if complexfunction(resource.data)' with complexfunction checking all kind of things on the fields of the document, and maybe even checking some related documents via the get and exists functions

Comment: I recommend giving it a try with a specific rule, but the logic is that the rules engine only allows operations for which it can guarantee the conditions are met. It is pretty smart about that. , but if it can't meet this guarantee it will reject the operation.

Comment: I will post a new question with a clear example